# Regenerating a custom list form .designer.cs file

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, list-form

I'm writing a custom list form in VS2010, but I can't get the .designer.cs file to regenerate to properly reference the controls in the aspx file. I've tried deleting the designer file, but the "Convert to Web Application" button that I'd usually use to regenerate the designer file isn't there. I could manually write out the designer file, but I think that would stop it from auto-updating with further changes. The file is under Source Control, if that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you following any tutorial ?

Comment: @TimeToThine I was roughly following [this one](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project-part-2/) to start off with, but I abandoned it as soon as I'd got a basic form displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing/Incomplete designer file causes Visual studio (VS) to fail the build. 
First of all try to switch between designer and source view, it sometimes solve the problem.
If it didn't work for you, try solution on this post.

http://swsharinginfo.blogspot.in/2012/03/regenerate-designer-file-in-visual.html